# Angular one of the conditions is to check the password field for certain characters only [! @ $% & *]

Tags: html, regex, angular, angular8

```js
checkParams(event) {

    if (event.length > 8 && event.length <= 30) {
        this.passLength = true;
    } else {
        this.passLength = false;
    }
//quantity check

    if (event.search(/[0-9]/) > -1) {
        this.passNumbers = true;
    } else {
        this.passNumbers = false;
    }
//number check

    if (event.search(/[!@$%&*]+/) > -1) {
        this.passSpecial = true;
    } else {
        this.passSpecial = false;
    }
//character check

    if (event.search(/[a-z].*[A-Z]|[A-Z].*[a-z]/) > -1) {
        this.passUpper = true;
    } else {
        this.passUpper = false;
    }
//check upper case 

    if (event.search(/^\S*$/)) {
        this.passSpace = false;
    } else {
        this.passSpace = true;
    }
//check whitespace
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        if (event.search(/[!@$%&*]+/) > -1 && event.search(/[~`#^()_={}[\]:;,.<>+\/?-]+/) <= -1) {
        this.passSpecial = true;
    } else {
        this.passSpecial = false;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the following single pattern:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!@$%&*]).{9,30}$
```

Your Angular JS code:

```
if (event.search(/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!@$%&*]).{9,30}$/) > -1) {
    this.passValid = true;
}
else {
    this.passValid = false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought to do it, but I need the password entry conditions to change color.
For example:
- password must contain special symbols (*,!, $,%, &, @)
- password must contain digits
- password shall not contain gaps
- passwords must match
if true, then highlight in green

Comment: Yes, but how do you propose to handle multiple logical conditions with a single color?  E.g. missing numbers and missing capitals...what is the color?

Comment: I will share a screenshot. https://paste.pics/072d121589b5364008db20340c04d1cb

Comment: "password must contain special symbols" - Um. There are quite a lot more special symbols than those. And, honestly, most such requirements just make passwords that are [easy to brute force and hard to remember](https://xkcd.com/936/). I mean, no gaps? Why? :-\